# Android Studio Error fail to establish apply plugin com.android.application

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue

Comment: We need more information like your Gradle file(s)

Comment: I found solution problem was with classpath     dependencies {
        //classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

Comment: It works for me, Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google releases a new build tool and old makes deprecated I think.

We used: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'`

but new version was released and this error occured.

Just replace previous with new version:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'`

So check latest build tool from: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Stable build tool last version is (I think): `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`

Comment: Note: the current version of the release of gradle is updated from time to time, and the `build.gradle` script needs updating accordingly. This is particularly common when trying to build an Android project that hasn't been updated for a while.